# javascript initialize each value in the object with a default value

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to count the number of links in a page:

```
let temp = {}
for (const page of pages) { 
    let count = temp[page.outgoingLinks.length];
    if (!count) {
        count = 0;
    } 
        count++;
    
    temp[page.outgoingLinks.length]=count;
}
```

Sorry for variable names like temp as I am trying show some code which would help you understand what I am trying to do. Here, I would like to avoid the need for the if check that initializes the value.

In this example, the default value is an integer. But I would like to store even an Array there, something like defaultdict in python. Any ideas on how I can do it in JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like Python's `defaultdict` in JavaScript, however you can have a default value when accessing the property by using the [nullish-coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```
let count = temp[page.outgoingLinks.length] ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

**To avoid the need for the if check that initializes the value**

```
for (const page of pages) { 
   temp[page.outgoingLinks.length] = temp[page.outgoingLinks.length] ? temp[page.outgoingLinks.length]++ : 0;
}
```

here you can direclty use ternary operator to do so.

Answer (score 1):

As you want multiple default values, you could create an object that contains the default values. This object can be defined in a helper function that takes an argument which specifies the type of default value you want and returns a function that can be called with the value.

If that value is `undefined` or `null`, this function returns the required type of default value.

```js
function getInitializer(typeOfDefault) {
  const defaults = {
    arr: [0, 0, 0],
    num: 0,
    emptyString: ''
  };

  return (value) => value ?? defaults[typeOfDefault];
}

// default number
const initialize = getInitializer('num');
const a = initialize(0);
console.log(a);

// default array
const initialize2 = getInitializer('arr');
const b = initialize2(null);
console.log(b);
```